Database Tuning to address poor performance
I'm not a DB Administrator but am looking for advice on tuning our MySQL database. It's a small storefront that is running Prestashop, and lags out for several minutes when saving changes to a product pack. That is, a product that is made up of 2 or more other products.
I just ran MySQLTuner-Perl and it looks alright for the most part, but there are several points flagged for review.
[!!] Aborted connections: 6.83% (337899/4948004)
[!!] CPanel and Flex system skip-name-resolve should be on
[!!] Joins performed without indexes: 10213707

I suspect the 10M Joins performed without indexes is the likely culprit here, but not entirely sure what that means or how it should be addressed.
The server has tons of spare memory so I could increase the allocation 2-3x as a temporary bandaid, but I imagine this won't be resolved until I figure out the indexing issue. Any advice or clarity on these results would be greatly appreciated.


Increase innodb_buffer_pool_size to 70% of available RAM.

I recommend you delete MySQLTuner and forget it exists. It often gives advice that is not actionable, misleading, or plain wrong. I don't recommend using it.
I would use the slow query log to find out which queries are taking the longest, either individually or in aggregate (i.e. many quick queries can cause a lot of burden on the server, as much as a few costly queries).
A free tool to analyze your slow query log and report the top worst queries is pt-query-digest. This blog gives a good introduction to using it: https://www.percona.com/blog/identifying-high-load-mysql-slow-query-log-pt-query-digest/
Once you get the list of the most costly queries, you'll likely learn that it's just a handful of queries that are causing the problem. Maybe it's even just one query, run frequently.
Then you can focus on optimizing these few queries. Often they just need a new index to help them do searches or joins without scanning the whole table. You might like my presentation How to Design Indexes, Really (video).
Or maybe a table has grown very large with old data you don't need, and the best thing to do is truncate it once in a while to start over.

Thank you for the detailed answer. Upon further testing with slow log query, we've identified several modules that were basically assaulting the MySQL database, one of which (a payment module) generated 68MB of query logs each time we saved changes to a product. It will take some time to fix these but feels much better knowing what's going on behind the scenes.
